# Xamarin iOS - Como gerar um ad-hoc usando VS com Mac remoto

Tags: ios, xamarin, iphone

dúvida técnica!
Tenho um projeto Xamarin iOS, estou usando um iMAC Virtual com XCode contratado para rodar a aplicação em um simulador. Faço a conexão de emparelhamento e roda a aplicação. Lentidão, uso de simulador, até ai normal... e vida que segue!
Chegou a hora de testar no aparelho físico, fiz inúmeros testes mas não tive sucesso...

Nesse cenário: 
- Maquina de Dev com Windows 10, VS 2019;
- iMac Cloud com Xcode Emparelhado, tenho conta Apple Dev contratado;
- Iphone 6 atualizado iOS 12.2;

Consigo gerar um pacote?
Como instalo meu app no iphone? 
Quero só abrir e testar por enquanto, depois vou colocar na loja, por hora é só testes... alguém já passou por isso e poderia me dar uma luz?

Obs: Consigo rodar o projeto na máquina iMac Cloud.

Consigui gerar o arquivamento, mas na hora de fazer o adhoc ou outra coisa não consegui.

Desde de já agradeço.

Comment: Ola Carlos, Bem vindo ao SOpt. - Vale a pena conferir nosso [Tour]. - A comunidade provavelmente vai precisar de mais informações para te ajudar, como por exemplo: **Algum erro é gerado?**, **Você consegue selecionar o iPhone como destino do build?**, **O projeto no XCode está assinando de modo automático ou manual?**, **Já verificou se a arquitetura da build é compatível com o iPhone?**...

Comment: Olá Icaro, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Você consegue selecionar o iPhone como destino do build? Não consigo... estou em uma máquina windows!

Comment: Algum erro é gerado?Não é feito o arquivamento bonitinho... na hora de publicar não consigo escolher meu perfil no VS

Comment: O projeto no XCode está assinando de modo automático ou manual? Fiz Manual... o Automático não consegui definir...

Comment: Já verificou se a arquitetura da build é compatível com o iPhone? Sim é compativel estou pegando versão antiga do Iphone 5S para frentre...

Comment: "Estou em uma máquina Windows" - Seu XCode não está em um Mac os?

Comment: Ahh, Acho que entendi agora, você esta desenvolvendo em uma máquina windows e fazendo o build em uma máquina mac os online alugada

Comment: Sim o XCode está em uma máquina Mac cloud... Uso uma máquina contratada do macincloud.com! Faço o emparelhamento pelo VS e depois rodo em um simulador do iphone... o que eu quero agora é testar no iphone físico

Comment: Então para você instalar em seu iPhone você provavelmente vai ter que gerar um **ad-hoc**, para isso funcionar vc também tem que registrar o iphone como device dev, eu não achei um link bom mostrando isso. Vale a pena voce editar a pergunta e colocar essas informações.

Comment: Assim... eu imaginei que precisaria fazer algo assim... e justamente é nisso que estou tendo dificuldade! Eu registrei meu iphone na conta Dev da Apple, em Device... tbm criei o o registro do App... mas estando no VS quando vou gerar o Ad-Hoc não aparece minha conta e nem meu projeto, mesmo estando emparelhado! Tem algum outro lugar no visual studio que tenho que definir usuário da apple? ou basta estar emparelhado?

Comment: Eu não tenho experiência nesse desenvolvimento via VS então não vou conseguir te ajudar =( . Mas vale a pena você atualizar a pergunta para deixar mais claro o objetivo de gerar um ad-hoc usando VS com mac remoto. Isso também vai levar sua pergunta  novamente para o topo aumentando a chance de alguém da comunidade com essa experiência ver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consegui resolver o problema!
Pelo que parece eu estava gerando incorretamente o registro na página developer da apple:
1) Deve se ter o registro do certificado de desenvolvedor para aplicativos;
1.1) Deve se ter tbm o certificado de distribuidor ad-hoc;
2) Deve se Registrar o Device que será utilizado para teste;
3) Deve se Criar um profile de provisionamento manual com base no certificado desenvolvedor;
3.) Deve se criar o profile de distribuição com base no certificado ad-hoc;
4) Na máquina Macincloud deve-se abrir o XCode e autenticar na conta, baixar os certificados fazer o download;
5) no Visual Studio, Emparelhar com a máquina MacinCloud;
6) Arquivar o pacote da aplicação iOS, com base da conta de Desenvolvedor e certificado de desenvolvedor com profile determinado;
7) Após fazer a distribuição usando Ad-Hoc, utilizar o certificado de distribuidor de app, com o profile de teste que foi criado;
8) Será gerado o arquivo ipa, que é uma espécie de pacote zip da aplicação validado;
9) Conecte com iTunes, pode ser a versão for Windows mesmo, arraste o pacote ipa para o dispositivo e assim se concluí a instalação e distribuição por ad-hoc;

Acho que é isso, se alguem tiver algum observação sobre o processo, ficarei grato pela ajuda!
Até mais!